# Remove empty quote in a nested list using python doesn't work

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I make simple script to test how I can remove empty quote from a list. The output actually coming from a device output and i save the output onto csv file.

This is my code

```
 mylist = [['Local Interface', '', 'Parent Interface', '', 'Chassis Id', '', 
 '', '', '', 'Port info', '', '', '', '', 'System Name'], ['ge-0/0/1', '', 
 '', '', '', ' -', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' 
 606', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'myhost-re01', '', '', '', ''], ['ge- 
 4/0/7', '', '', '', '', ' -', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 
 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' 628', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'myhost-re01', '', 
 '', '', ''], ['ge-4/0/6', '', '', '', '', ' -', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
 '', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' 629', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
 'myhost-re01', '', '', '', ''], ['ge-0/0/4', '', '', '', '', ' -', '', '', 
 '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' 138739712', '', '', '', '', 
 'PE12XC1010', '', '', '', ''], ['ge-0/0/2', '', '', '', '', ' -', '', '', 
 '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' gei_1/5', '', '', '', '', 
 '', 'PE13XC1011', '', '', '', '', ''], ['ge-3/3/0', '', '', '', '', ' -', 
 '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 0c:12:12:c7:c1:f7', ' gei_2/3', '', '', 
 '', '', '', 'PEUTV01-01XT', '', '', ''], ['ge-3/3/4', '', '', '', '', ' - 
 ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' f0:1c:2d:22:37:c0', ' 783', '', '', 
 '', '', '', '', '', 'myhost-re01', ''], ['{master}']]
 print(mylist)
 mylist = list(filter(None,mylist))
 print(mylist)
```

The print out before and after filtering is same.

Seems easy to resolve but not success so far...hope someone could help me. Thanks

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
**UPDATE1:**
I have json api below that need to be parsed with values. For example lldp info output to be add onto "lldpinfo" or data[2]

```
json1 = {
  "channel": "scanner",
  "action": "device_scan",
  "table": "D2",
  "device":[]
}
data = "hostname","ipaddress","lldpinfo"
```

The overall sample result when parse the value as below

```
{
  "channel": "scanner",
  "action": "device_scan",
  "table": "D2",
  "device": [
    [
      "hostname": "test1",
      "ipaddress": "192.1.1.1",
      "lldpinfo": [ 
       [
        "Local port": "xe-3/0/3.0", 
        "Port Info": "  ae31.0", 
        "Mac address": " b0:c6:9a:63:80:40", 
        "Chassis Id": "xe-0/1/3.0", 
        "Neighbour Host Name": "host.xsrt1.net"
       ],
       [
        "Local port": "xe-3/0/3.0", 
        "Port Info": "  ae31.0", 
        "Mac address": " b0:c6:9a:63:80:40", 
        "Chassis Id": "xe-0/1/3.0", 
        "Neighbour Host Name": "host.xsrt1.net"
       ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "hostnname": "test2",
      "ipaddress": "192.1.1.2",
      "lldpinfo": [
      {
      }
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From above result the lldp info details is parse in [] .I think it should be in {} like below...

```
"lldpinfo": [ 
 {
  "Local port": "xe-3/0/3.0", 
  "Port Info": "  ae31.0", 
  "Mac address": " b0:c6:9a:63:80:40", 
  "Chassis Id": "xe-0/1/3.0", 
  "Neighbour Host Name": "host.xsrt1.net"
  },
  {
   "Local port": "xe-3/0/3.0", 
   "Port Info": "  ae31.0", 
   "Mac address": " b0:c6:9a:63:80:40", 
   "Chassis Id": "xe-0/1/3.0", 
   "Neighbour Host Name": "host.xsrt1.net"
   }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
mylist = [['Local Interface', '', 'Parent Interface', '', 'Chassis Id', '',  '', '', '', 'Port info', '', '', '', '', 'System Name'], ['ge-0/0/1', '',  '', '', '', ' -', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', '  606', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'myhost-re01', '', '', '', ''], ['ge-  4/0/7', '', '', '', '', ' -', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' 628', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'myhost-re01', '',  '', '', ''], ['ge-4/0/6', '', '', '', '', ' -', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',  '', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' 629', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',  'myhost-re01', '', '', '', ''], ['ge-0/0/4', '', '', '', '', ' -', '', '',  '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' 138739712', '', '', '', '',  'PE12XC1010', '', '', '', ''], ['ge-0/0/2', '', '', '', '', ' -', '', '',  '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' gei_1/5', '', '', '', '',  '', 'PE13XC1011', '', '', '', '', ''], ['ge-3/3/0', '', '', '', '', ' -', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 0c:12:12:c7:c1:f7', ' gei_2/3', '', '',  '', '', '', 'PEUTV01-01XT', '', '', ''], ['ge-3/3/4', '', '', '', '', ' -  ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' f0:1c:2d:22:37:c0', ' 783', '', '',  '', '', '', '', '', 'myhost-re01', ''], ['{master}']]

mylist = list(map(lambda x: list(filter(None,x)), mylist))
print(mylist)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Local Interface', 'Parent Interface', 'Chassis Id', 'Port info', 'System Name'], ['ge-0/0/1', ' -', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', '  606', 'myhost-re01'], ['ge-  4/0/7', ' -', '  00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' 628', 'myhost-re01'], ['ge-4/0/6', ' -', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' 629', 'myhost-re01'], ['ge-0/0/4', ' -', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' 138739712', 'PE12XC1010'], ['ge-0/0/2', ' -', ' 00:2d:b3:c9:e2:f0', ' gei_1/5', 'PE13XC1011'], ['ge-3/3/0', ' -', ' 0c:12:12:c7:c1:f7', ' gei_2/3', 'PEUTV01-01XT'], ['ge-3/3/4', ' -  ', ' f0:1c:2d:22:37:c0', ' 783', 'myhost-re01'], ['{master}']]
```

Comment: possible to delete the first.... ['Local Interface', 'Parent Interface', 'Chassis Id', 'Port info', 'System Name'], empty [] and  ['{master}'] in the list?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand...Do you want to flatten the list?

Comment: No...If the list got empty [] and specific list that need to be deleted in this case ['Local Interface', 'Parent Interface', 'Chassis Id', 'Port info', 'System Name'], empty [] and ['{master}']...

Comment: list slicing `print(mylist[1:-1])` ?

Comment: it does remove ['{master}']... so can use slicing...to remove  ['Local Interface', 'Parent Interface', 'Chassis Id', 'Port info', 'System Name'] or any empty [] ?

Comment: Hi sir, the output above is on nested list [[],[],[]] format..can it be changed to [{},{},{}] ... I can see that both format able to be viewed valid on json viewer... which one shall be used if i want to parse above information to another existing json file. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list comprehension to exclude falsey items (in this case empty strings) from your nested list.

```
mylist = [[x for x in line if x] for line in mylist]
```

See [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

This is one list comprehension:

```
[x for x in line if x]
```

nested inside another:

```
[... for line in mylist]
```

giving you a nested list as output.

Comment: You also filter `None`, `False`, and `0`

Comment: @ezdazuzena It's a nested list of strings, not of `None`, `False` and `0`. It has the same effect as `filter(None, ...)`

Comment: Hi...this method also works. Thank you. What is the different compare of using comprehension and lambda operator?

Comment: @chenoi In Python 3, `filter` and `map` do not return lists. They return iterable objects (which can be transformed to lists). A list comprehension is a syntax purely for building a list in a transparent way. Use whichever you find more readable.

Comment: Ok..got it...'list comprehension is a syntax purely for building a list in a transparent way'.... does it care if the list is nested or not?

Comment: @chenoi You can nest comprehensions just as you nest lists. The code in my answer is one comprehension `[x for x in line if x]` nested inside another `[... for line in mylist]`.

Comment: @chenoi See [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension and filtering out those items of your sublist that equal to an empty string

```
[[sl for sl in sublist if sl != ''] for sublist in mylist]
```

Loops over your list

```
[.. for sublist in mylist]
```

and for each sublist only takes those that are not `''`

```
[sl for sl in sublist if sl != '']
```

If you want to use `filter` this would be

```
[filter(lambda x: x != '', sublist) for sublist in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `filter` function in list comprehensions:

```
mylist = mylist = [['Local Interface', '', 'Parent Interface', '', 'Chassis Id', '',
 '', '', '', 'Port info', '', '', '', '', 'System Name'], ['ge-0/0/1', '',
 '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['{master}']]

new_list = [list(filter(None,n)) for n in mylist]

print(new_list)
```

**output**

```
[['Local Interface', 'Parent Interface', 'Chassis Id', 'Port info', 'System Name'], ['ge-0/0/1'], ['{master}']]
```

Comment: Thank you...im getting  [<filter object at 0x7f033380ef98>, <filter object at 0x7f0332945cc0>, <filter object at 0x7f0332945d30>, <filter object at 0x7f0332945da0>, <filter object at 0x7f0332945e10>, <filter object at 0x7f0332945e80>, <filter object at 0x7f0332945ef0>, <filter object at 0x7f0332945f60>, <filter object at 0x7f0332945fd0>]

Comment: Changed the answer